# How to show/hide a select input according to a value chosen in a previous select input reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, select, onchange

I am new to reactjs, and here I have a form, and in that form I have an input select with two value options.

And the first value option should allow me to bring up a second input select with these value options, and the second nothing at all.

I made my form and for the first input select I manage to do an onChange method, to retrieve the chosen value, but now how to do a test on the chosen value, to display or not the second input select ?

And how to show or hide this second input select ?

**My Form**

```js
// methode that retrieve the chosen value in input select
const handleOptionChange = (event: any) => {
    console.log(event);
};


const FormContent = (props: any) => {
    const { control, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
    const { Option } = Select;
    
    const onSubmit = handleSubmit((data) => {

        console.log(data);
        
    });

    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            
            <Row gutter={8}>
                <Col md={12} lg={12} sm={24}>
                    <div className="ant-form-item">
                        <label className="label">Nom Utilisateur <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <Controller
                            // as={inputField("Nom Utilisateur")}
                            name="username"
                            control={control}
                            defaultValue={""}
                            rules={{ required: true }}
                            render={props => (<><Input name={props.name} defaultValue={props.value} className="ant-form-item-control" placeholder="Nom Utilisateur" /></>)}
                        />
                        {errors.username && "First name is required"}
                    </div>
                </Col>
                <Col md={12} lg={12} sm={24}>
                    <div className="ant-form-item">
                        <label className="label">Mot de passe <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <Controller
                            // as={inputPassField()}
                            name="password"
                            control={control}
                            defaultValue={""}
                            rules={{ required: true }}
                            render={props => (<Input.Password placeholder="Mot de passe" />)}
                        />
                        {errors.password && "First name is required"}
                    </div>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row gutter={8}>
               
                <Col md={12} lg={12} sm={24}>
                    <div className="ant-form-item">
                        <label className="label">Profile<span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <Controller
                            name="profile"
                            control={control}
                            defaultValue={""}
                            rules={{ required: true }}
                            render={({ onChange, value, name }) => (
                                <Select
                                    showSearch
                                    placeholder="Select a person"
                                    onChange={(event) => {
                                        onChange(event)
                                        handleOptionChange(event)
                                    }}
                                    value={value ? value : ""}
                                    // name={name}
                                    optionFilterProp="children"
                                    filterOption={(input, option: any) =>
                                        option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                                    }>
                                    <option key="b2b_user" value="B2B_CLIENT">B2B_USER</option>
            <option key="app_user" value="APPLICATION_USER">USER_SIMPLE</option>
                                </Select>)}

                        />
                        {errors.profile && "Profile is required"}
                    </div>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            
            <Row gutter={8}>
                <Col md={12} lg={12} sm={24}>

                    <Flex alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
                        <Button onClick={() => props.onClose()} icon={<CloseOutlined />} size="small" className="mr-3" type="text">Annuler</Button>

                        <Button icon={<CheckCircleOutlined />} type='primary' htmlType='submit'>
                            Valider
            </Button>
                    </Flex>

                </Col>
            </Row>
        </form>);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Second input to show/hide**

```js
export const SelectCompanyField = () => {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(10);
    const { data, error } = useSWR<ServerResponse, any>(companyUrls.base + `?page:${page}&perPage:${perPage}`, url => getDataByParams(companyUrls.base, { page: '' + page, perPage: '' + perPage }));
    console.log("Data", data, "Error", error);
    console.log(data?.entities);

    return (
        <Select
            showSearch
            placeholder="Choisir une compagnie"
            optionFilterProp="children"
            filterOption={(input, option: any) =>
                option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
            }
        >
            {data?.entities.map(d => (
                <option value={d.index} key={d.id} >
                    {d.name}
                </option>
            ))}

        </Select>
    );
};
// the second input select to show/hide 
<Col md={24} lg={24} sm={24}>
                    <div className="ant-form-item">
                        <label className="label">Compagnie <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <Controller
                            as={SelectCompanyField()}
                            name="company"
                            control={control}
                            defaultValue={""}
                            rules={{ required: false }}
                        />
                        {errors.company && "Company is required"}
                    </div>
 </Col>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like...

```
const [firstOptionValue, setFirstOptionValue] = useState(null)

const handleOptionChange = (event: any) => {
    setFirstOptionValue(event.target.value)
};
```

Then when you want to conditionally render the second select...

```
{firstOptionValue && <SecondSelectContainer/>}
```

So whatever is in `SecondSelectContainer` will only render if `firstOptionValue` is not falsey.

Comment: Hi @Bafsky, this is what I was looking for, but if I want to test the value of the selected input, to display or not the second input select ?

Comment: If you only want to show the 2nd input if the 1st one has a value of "YES" you would do... `{(firstOptionValue === 'YES') && <SecondSelectContainer/>}`

Comment: Hi @Bafsky, your solution works but when I choose a value in my new input that appears, this value and his name does not appear in my data after submitting the form. I did like this: ```{firstOptionValue && <SelectCompanyField />}```

Comment: You should accept this answer since it answers your question. And then start a new question if needed.